# How to choose r(t) for a vector line integral?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors

**Question:** Let C be the upper half of the unit circle oriented clockwise and let F = ⟨2y + 1, −2x − 1⟩, the value of $\int_{C} F \cdot \,dr$ is?

**Answer:** $2\pi + 2$

I understand how to plug things in and complete this portion $\int_{C}\vec{F}(r(t))\cdot\vec{r}'(t)\,\,dt$ and how the parameter is $0\to\pi$, what I don't understand about this problem is how I was supposed to determine that $\vec{r}(t) = \langle -\cos(t),\sin(t)\rangle$.

Comment: I would probably have noted that switching the orientation just switches the sign, and then used the more standard $r(t)=\langle \cos(t),\sin(t) \rangle$ for $0 \leq t \leq \pi$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Curvilinear (polar coordinates) take advantage of the spherical symmetry of the  curve.

Curvilinear coordinates and linear (Cartesian) coordinates both represent in this case $\Bbb R^2$ equally well (they span $\Bbb R^2$). You can change from one to the other via this coordinate transformation, $$x=rcos\theta$$

$$y=rsin\theta$$

Here $r$ is the radius of the circle not to be confused with your use of it.

Also typically an n dimensional surface (line curve would be $n=1$) can be parameterized with $n$ variables regardless of coordinate system, if that part was not understood.

Answer (score 2):

Normally, when you parameterize circles, you are better off using sines and cosines. A typical parameterization of the unit circle is $x = \cos t, y = \sin t$, but this moves counterclockwise. To move in the other direction, negate the $x$...

You can also parameterize directly, remembering that the equation of the unit circle is $x^2+y^2=1$, and since you want the upper half, it comes out to $y = \sqrt{1-x^2}$ with $x \in [-1,1]$. It would come out to the same answer, but with more arithmetic....